# How to use instagram as a chatbot and i already use facebook messenger for the same

Tags: facebook, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

I created an app for my chatbot application and integrate it on Facebook messenger this works perfectly, Now I want to integrate the same on Instagram so I created the business account named "test_MyApplicationName" and then connect it with the same Facebook app which I use for messenger. also created a webhook and give all permissions which are necessary for IG but still, I don't get any response from Instagram messaging to my backend(I also added the recipient/test user in the app). So

1. I request to you guys please help me to achieve this.
2. For Instagram is it necessary to have a live/verified app?
   Thanks
   Kartikey Gupta

Answer (score 0):

You must use a test account for that.

Go to app dashboard-> roles -> test user.

create a test user with pages_metadata, instagram_basic, pages_messaging, instagram_messaging permission.

after creating a test account, log in with that. Create a Facebook page after that go to Instagram open an account using Facebook.

• test in the account should start with test_ example:
test_albert, test_username.
• goto facebook page setting -> Instagram -> connect to Instagram
• go to Instagram settings -> privacy -> Allow access to the message should turn on.
• Connect your app again with the test Facebook account and select the Instagram account while connecting.

P.S: you must have followers between 1-100k to receive an Instagram webhook event from that particular account.

Comment: Why do I have to create a fb page? with the test user account, not able to create Instagram account all it is saying is "Sorry, something went wrong creating your account. Please try again soon." no matter how later I try. Please help.